# NodeJS and Express - Safely differentiate between clients that make the request

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication, cross-domain

Currently I am working on a project that needs to keep track and authenticate users from different clients. Each of these clients is an individual website. In the database, they are stored with their credentials like this:

```js
email: {
  type: String,
  required: true
},
security: {
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  apiKey: {
    type: String
  }
},
client: {
  type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Client',
  required: true
},
```

They should be able to login using either email/password combination if they come from the client itself, either email/apiKey combination if they are trying to interact directly with the API.

Well, my problem right now, is that I don't see any reliable way of authenticating them on the server, based from where their request came from.

Also, the client application has READ rights from the server to display items even if the user is not authenticated.

How can I make sure, that these endpoints for reading data, can't be accessed by anyone outside the client if they don't have the email/apiKey combination.

I've looked into the following ways of solving this:

- Tried to rely on the Origin header, which I don't think it is a good idea. It seems that it can be changed from Postman and set to whatever you like.
- Tried to rely on the IP which comes along with the request. This seems like the best idea up until now, because each client website has a static IP and this value I don't think that can be changed externally.
- I also tried generating a token that has to be passed at the same time with each request from the client. But this isn't a good idea either, because this token can be seen in the Network tab and copied.

Do you have any suggestions? Should I go with the IP way? Or is there an even better solutions to this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Daniel. If I understood you correctly, the usual flow is  that the client gets to an endpoint where he provides email and pwd, then the server checks them, and provide a token in return if everything is. After that, client will provide that token in headers and server will authenticate in a middle ware for each request. If you are not behind https/SSL or you are affraid token can be stolen somehow, you could sign the IP address in the same token and check for a malicious behavior if the real address differs from signed one.

Comment: You can filter or identify that the ips are from the sites you expect as well, not only to detect malicious situations